# Can I force the sequence of services in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I am working on a diskless system that starts up over PXE, with a read-only root directory mounted over NFS. I have set it up, so it configures its hostname during boot, and at a later point, mounts and configures some system directories. This is the service that configures the hostname:

```
root@node080027eb24b8:~# cat /lib/systemd/system/sethostname.service
[Unit]
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
After=local-fs.target
DefaultDependencies=false

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sethostname
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

and:

```
root@node080027eb24b8:~# ll /etc/systemd/system/network.target.wants
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Feb 19 11:39 sethostname.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/sethostname.service
```

A writable `/home` is mounted by `/etc/fstab`. At a later stage, I provide writable `/var` and `/tmp` directories by creating `/home/var/[hostname]` amd `/home/tmp/[hostname]` and using `mount -o bind` to bind `/var` rsp `/tmp` to these. The service that takes care of this is `prepsysdirs`:

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/prepsysdirs.service
[Unit]
Description=Script to run after fstab mount for /home/
Requires=home.mount
After=home.mount
RequiresMountsFor=/home
Before=munge.service slurmd.service
 
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/prepsysdirs
 
[Install]
WantedBy=munge.service
```

and:

```
root@node080027eb24b8:~# ll /etc/systemd/system/munge.service.wants
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Feb 26 15:16 prepsysdirs.service -> /lib/systemd/system/prepsysdirs.service
```

Thus far, this all works. However, it looks like `munge.service` starts up before `prepsysdirs.service` has done its work:

```
root@node080027eb24b8:~# systemctl status munge
● munge.service - MUNGE authentication service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/munge.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-02-26 16:15:30 UTC; 30s ago
       Docs: man:munged(8)
    Process: 375 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/munged $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4ms

Feb 26 16:15:30 node080027eb24b8 systemd[1]: Starting MUNGE authentication service...
Feb 26 16:15:30 node080027eb24b8 munged[381]: munged: Error: Failed to check logfile "/var/log/munge/munged.log": Permission denied
Feb 26 16:15:30 node080027eb24b8 systemd[1]: munge.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 26 16:15:30 node080027eb24b8 systemd[1]: munge.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 16:15:30 node080027eb24b8 systemd[1]: Failed to start MUNGE authentication service.
```

If I try to start it up manually after logging in, it doesn't have this problem.

So, the question is: How can I ensure that `munge` doesn't start before `prepsysdirs` has run?

Comment: `munged: Error: Failed to check logfile "/var/log/munge/munged.log": Permission denied` some services can't start while the log is not accessible. dod you read and fixed this error? moreover mostly you need tmpfs or similar that temporary data can be written, else you may force either to discard any logs

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was the missing `Type=...` in `cat /lib/systemd/system/prepsysdirs.service`:

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/prepsysdirs.service
[Unit]
Description=Script to run after fstab mount for /home/
Requires=home.mount
After=home.mount
RequiresMountsFor=/home
Before=munge.service slurmd.service
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/prepsysdirs
 
[Install]
WantedBy=munge.service
```

After adding that line, it works!